# Searching infinite lists of lists of list of list... (that can go on for ever) with string that defines how many lists to look for

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a path, this path isn't always the same, a user may enter for example /main/jumanji/hacks but then enter /main/users/pirate/cool/beans

From this I want to check if that path exists in a fake enviroment for example /main/jumanji/hacks would be something like folders.contains(main)? folders[main].contains? jumanji, folders[main][jumanji].contains? hacks, 
return folders[main][jumanji][hacks].Files
or
return folders[main][jumanji][hacks].Folders

problem is I don't know what the user is going to write and, potentially, I have lists of lists of list, that could go on forever. How do I check if the path exists and get the data from it?

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string path = "/main/users/pirate/cool";

    public bool Exists()
    {
        string[] folders = path.Split('\\');

        //List<Folder> folders // assume it's already populated

        // for(folders) contain /"main"/ 
            // for(folders main) contains? users
                // for folders(main, users) contains? pirate
                    // for folders(main, users, pirate) contains? cool

                        // return folders[main][users][pirate][cool].Files
                        // or
                        // return folders[main][users][pirate][cool].Folder

        return false;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Folder
{
    public string Path;
    public List<string> Folders;
    public List<File> Files;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class File
{
    public string Name;
    public string Text;
    public string Extension;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed several modifications to your code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Folder
{
    // Supposing you have the name of the folder instead of its path
    // Otherwise, you just have to check if the paths are equals
    public string Name;
    public List<Folder> Folders; // Folder instead of string
    public List<File> Files;
}

public bool Exists( string path )
{
    string[] hierarchy = path.Split('\\');

    List<Folder> folders = GetRootFolders() ; // assume it's already populated

    for( int i = 0 ; i < hierarchy.Length ; ++i )
    {
        if( folders == null || folders.Count == 0 )
            return false ;

        Folder desiredFolder = folders.Find( f => f.Name.Equals( hierarchy[i] ));

        if( desiredFolder == null )
            return false ;

        folders = desiredFolder.Folders;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The given code is way too complexely given.

Over which folders do you do your for's ? I guess it is the string[] folders, so rename the List to something else.
one of the returns does folders[main][users]....[cool].Folder but this will not work due to it being already the folder.

Can you please rewrite the given code and make more clear what you want? What are these paths? Are this system paths, game paths, ...